# What is the best approach to evaluate the effect of an intervention on different segments?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, causality

I have a dataset post A/B test which looks like this:

```
Group     | Segment         | Purchase ($)
Treatment | Small Business  | 10
Treatment | Medium Business | 15
Control   | Small Business  | 8
Control   | Medium Business | 8...
```

Now, I want to evaluate the impact of the treatment on Purchase ($) and if it was different by segment.

I can think of 4 options but I am not sure what to select:

1. Run t-test for each segment separately. If so, what are the caveats?
2. Run heterogeneous treatment estimation (HTE). If so, what to be aware of?
3. Run Causal Forest. If so, what to be aware of?
4. Uplift Model (regression model). If so, what to consider?

I would appreciate any tips.
Thanks!

Comment: I am thinking of one option, a linear model.

Comment: @user2974951 - I thought that too, but why would the OP be looking at some of those advanced models before looking at the fundamentals?  @ ee8291, what have you looked at in the way of fundamentals?  Have you tried a basic linear model, and in what ways was it insufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the treatment was assigned randomly, after coding `Small Business` as 0 and `Medium Business` as 1, the OLS coefficient $\beta_1$ will give you an unbiased estimate of the average causal effect of treatment on purchases for Small Businesses, while $\beta_1+\beta_3$ that for Medium Businesses.

$$purchases = \beta_0 + \beta_1 treatment +\beta_2 SegmentSize + \beta_3 treatment *SegmentSize  + \epsilon$$

I find the menu of your exotic options to be a curious one, especially since it does not seem to include the good old linear regression model. You'll get a lot more value out of mastering one statistical model such as linear regression than from superficially acquainting yourself with a whole host of exotic models.